# Using WooCommerce API to change the [shipping_lines][method_title]

Tags: php, api, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm currently using https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/ to change the shipping type to another one when some conditions are met in an API system.

Currently i'm having trouble just updating that same line, using the api example to update 2 lines, just creates a new shipping line, and i do not want to do that.

What would i have to send in data to just update the shipping method, and not create more shipping lines.

Under the code creates a new line i wooCommerce under shipping line instead of updating it:

$data =  array( "shipping_lines" => array( 0 => array( 'method_title' => $newShippingMethode, 'method_id' => 'flat_rate' ) ) );

is being sendt to:

$woocommerce->put('orders/' . $wooOrder["id"], $data)

Next solution was to get the previous shipping line and just change the one line, and send it back up to wooCommerce with all of the data, not just the lines i want to edit:

$current = $wooOrder["shipping_lines"]; $current[0]["method_title"] = $newShippingMethode;

$data =  array( "shipping_lines" => array( 0 => array( $currentT[0], ) ) );

This returns:

woocommerce_rest_invalid_shipping_item, transport-id required

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the $data array variable. Since $currentT was already an array, the variable did not have to be assigned like this: 0 => array(currentT); removing the wrap solved the problem.

Comment: please use `` to add the code blocks.